# why does my loop behave differently on different occasions?

Tags: python

i am trying to write a program that switches the order of the values in the list "b". I wanted to achieve this by creating another list "c" as the switched list and then change "b" to "c". For some reason the program worked for the first loop, but from the second time on the values i intend to change in "c" magically changed in "b" as well. I am noob so this might be something obvious but pls help.

```
fin = open("shuffle.in", "r")
fout = open("shuffle.out", "w")

n = int(fin.readline())
a = list(map(int,fin.readline().split()))
b = list(map(int,fin.readline().split()))
ar = [0] * n
c = [0] * n
for i in range(n):
   ar[a[i] - 1] = i + 1
print(ar)

for j in range(3):
   for i in range(n):
      print(ar[i] - 1)
      print(b[i])
      c[ar[i] - 1] = b[i]
      print(c)
      print("b:", b)
   b = c
   print("b:", b)
for i in b:
   fout.write(str(i))
   fout.write("\n")
```

Test data:

```
5
1 3 4 5 2
1234567 2222222 3333333 4444444 5555555
```

the output is suppose to be this:

```
1234567
5555555
2222222
3333333
4444444
```

Comment: It's not obvious (to me) how you derive that output from the input shown. Perhaps you could explain a little more

Comment: In the first pass through the loop you have `b = c` so of course `b` and `c` are the same thing in the second pass through the loop. Nothing magic about it. Perhaps you wanted `b = c.copy()`.